# Python sorted function

Tags: python

Can someone explain why below lambda sorted return this result?

## Example 1

```
>> sorted([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], key=lambda x: abs(5-x))
[5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9]
```

## Example 2

```
sorted ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], key=lambda x: abs(2-x))
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I understand how normal student.age acs sorting work but not the example at top

```
>>student_objects = [
        Student('john', 'A', 15),
        Student('jane', 'B', 12),
        Student('dave', 'B', 10),
]
>> sorted(student_objects, key=lambda student: student.age)   # sort by age
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key function returns the value by which sorting takes place. If you want to understand `abs(5 - x)` influences the sort, calculate the values for the given list:

```
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> key = lambda x: abs(5 - x)
>>> [(v, key(v)) for v in values]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 0), (6, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (9, 4)]
```

So `sorted()` will put the list in the order that the *key values* would be sorted into. For `5`, the key returns `0`, and that's the lowest value and would come first. For `1` and `9`, the key returns `4`, and those then are sorted last. Anywhere the key produces equal values (like `3` for both the input values `2` and `8`), the inputs are kept in their original order:

```
>>> sorted([(v, key(v)) for v in values], key=lambda vk: vk[1])  # sort on the key output
[(5, 0), (4, 1), (6, 1), (3, 2), (7, 2), (2, 3), (8, 3), (1, 4), (9, 4)]
>>> #^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^
```

What `sorted()` then returns, are the original input values alone, without the outputs of the sort key.

In the end, the key caused the values to be sorted by *distance from `5`*. The values closest to 5 come first, the values furthest away come last.

Comment: "In the end, the key caused the values to be sorted by distance from 5. The values closest to 5 come first, the values furthest away come last." 
what it mean by values closest come first ,how python judge this? 
because num 9 and num 1 both have same gap(4) to 5

Comment: @Tyler: I did cover that: their input order is kept. So `4` comes before `6` and `1` comes before `9` only because that's their order in the input list.

Comment: @Tyler: in other words, if you *reversed* the input list first, then you'd get `9` before `1`, as there is nothing to distinguish those two inputs when the key produces `4` for both. `[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` sorted with the same key produces `[5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 9, 1]`.

Comment: Thank , Amber answer is good but have to admit your last two sentence and the (reverse=True) example save my day

Answer (score 4):

`key` says "instead of sorting by the actual value at each position, compute a new value, sort by that, and then place the original values where the new ones would sort in the list".

So starting with the original list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The key lambda is called for each item, creating the following key values (in parens):

```
[1 (4),
 2 (3),
 3 (2),
 4 (1),
 5 (0),
 6 (1),
 7 (2),
 8 (3),
 9 (4)]
```

The list is then sorted in the order of the key values:

```
[5 (0),
 4 (1),
 6 (1),
 7 (2),
 3 (2),
 2 (3),
 8 (3),
 1 (4),
 9 (4)]
```

And then the original values from the list list are returned in that order:

```
[5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9]
```